# Matlab importing dataset

Tags: matlab, dataset

What is the difference between importing a dataset using matlab interface and using the dataset `function (dataset('File', 'fisher.csv', 'Delimiter', ','))` ?

For example when we import from UI we get:

- data array
- colheaders
- textdata

But when we use the function we just get a **single array**.

Can someone explain the way matlab loads datasets and the differences between other methods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab function `dataset` is not limited to `dataset('File','fisher.csv','Delimiter',',') )`.

The full usage is: `dataset('File',filename,'ParamName',Value)`, where `ParamName` can be many things.  'Delimiter' is just one example of a ParamName.

Here is a list of complete parameter name / value pairs: [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html)

For example, you'll notice that 'ReadVarNames' is a ParamName.  It's a logical that determines whether or not the first row contains variable names.  So if you want to use `dataset()` to import header lines:

```
dataset('File','fisher.csv','Delimiter',',', 'ReadVarNames', true);
```